# Why "NameError: name 'product_id_list' is not defined"=

Tags: python, pandas, function, loops, for-loop

I write this and i don't know  why product_id_list is not defined if i have defined it like 4 lines before.
Any suggestions? I thin identation is alright so I don't have any more ideas and I also searched around without luck.

Thank you!!

```
def make_dataSet_rowWise(reorder_product):
    print('unique Product in dataset = ', len(reorder_product.product_id.unique()))
    print('unique order_id in dataset = ', len(reorder_product.order_id.unique()))
    product_id_list = reorder_product.product_id.unique().tolist()
    product_id_list.append("order_id")
    product_id_dict = {}
    i = 0
    
for prod_id in product_id_list:
    product_id_dict[prod_id] = i
    i = i+1 
    product_id_df = pd.Dataframe(columns = product_id_list)
    row_list_all = []
    order_id_list = reorder_product.order_id.unique()
    i = 1
for id in order_id_list:
        #print(i)
    i = i+1
    np_zeros = np.zeros(shape = [len(product_id_list)-1])
    ordered_product_list = reorder_product.loc[reorder_product.order_id == id]["product_id"].tolist()
for order_prod in ordered_product_list:
    np_zeros[product_id_dict.get(order_prod)] = 1
    row_list = np_zeros.tolist()
    row_list.append(id)
    row_list_all.append(row_list)
return (row_list_all, product_id_list)

df_row_wise = make_dataSet_rowWise(reorder_product_99Pct)
product_id_df = pd.DataFrame(df_row_wise[0], columns = df_row_wise[1])
product_id_df.head()
```

The error I have is this one:

```
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-343-07bcac1b3b48> in <module>
      7     i = 0
      8 
----> 9 for prod_id in product_id_list:
     10     product_id_dict[prod_id] = i
     11     i = i+1

NameError: name 'product_id_list' is not defined
```

Comment: Is your indentation of the question correct? Becuase if so, `product_id_list` is defined within the scope of `make_dataSet_rowWise` so that for loop, outside the scope of the function, has no idea what it is. I'm guessing you mean to indent everything from that first `for` to the `return` line by 4 spaces

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already mentioned by the other answers, your indentation is wrong.
My recommendation is that you use a IDE like VSCode, there is also a free web version https://vscode.dev/

With such kind of IDE you can see that your indentation is wrong, check screenshot and line 27

[image]

There are also wrong indentations with the 3 for loops. The correct indentation should be as the following

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think your indentation may be wrong, the for-loops and return statement is out of the function (with your indentation) so I indented it so that it would still be part of the function...

```
def make_dataSet_rowWise(reorder_product):
    print('unique Product in dataset = ', len(reorder_product.product_id.unique()))
    print('unique order_id in dataset = ', len(reorder_product.order_id.unique()))
    product_id_list = reorder_product.product_id.unique().tolist()
    product_id_list.append("order_id")
    product_id_dict = {}
    i = 0
    
    for prod_id in product_id_list:
        product_id_dict[prod_id] = i
        i = i+1 
        product_id_df = pd.Dataframe(columns = product_id_list)
        row_list_all = []
        order_id_list = reorder_product.order_id.unique()
        i = 1
        for id in order_id_list:
                #print(i)
            i = i+1
            np_zeros = id.zeros(shape = [len(product_id_list)-1])
            ordered_product_list = reorder_product.loc[reorder_product.order_id == id]["product_id"].tolist()
            for order_prod in ordered_product_list:
                np_zeros[product_id_dict.get(order_prod)] = 1
                row_list = np_zeros.tolist()
                row_list.append(id)
                row_list_all.append(row_list)
    return (row_list_all, product_id_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm new here, but i think you either need to define the variable out of the scope of

```
def make_dataSet_rowWise(reorder_product):
```

OR indent the for loops to be inside

```
make_dataSet_rowWise
```